OroCommerce add promotion name in the shipping list
I am trying to add promotion name to the shopping list. Honestly don't know what template is responsible for that and how can I do that.
Long story short: I want to add a promotion name that fits to the requirements and is enabled in the shopping list.
I found this block
{% block __customer_user_shopping_list__line_items_widget %}
    {% set attr = layout_attr_defaults(attr, {
        '~class': ' my-shopping-list-datagrid-container'
    }) %}

    <div {{ block('block_attributes') }}>
        {{ block_widget(block) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

in vendor/oro/commerce/src/Oro/Bundle/ShoppingListBundle/Resources/views/layouts/default/imports/customer_user_shopping_list/layout.html.twig
Did anyone handle with case like this or similar?(customize shopping list view)
